# Want to get collectd CPU threshold warnings without CPU details

Tags: collectd

Dear collectd experts,

I am using collectd on many clients to send telemetry data to a central instance by network plugin. The clients are using for this collectd with a configuration containing among others:

```
LoadPlugin cpu
LoadPlugin network
<Plugin network>
        Server "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" "yyyy"
</Plugin>
```

This configuration also includes a threshold definition to send a warning in case the CPU is using more than 90% over a given time span. The configuration for this is:

```
LoadPlugin "threshold"
<Plugin "threshold">
    <Plugin "cpu">
        <Type "percent">
            Instance "user"
            # start to warn from 90%
            WarningMax 90
            # every 5 seconds -> 12 Hits (2 min)
            Hits 12
            # don't stop to warn until value drops below hyteresis
            Persist true
            # hyteresis means, we stop warning by 90% - 10% = 80%
            Hysteresis 10
        </Type>
    </Plugin>
</Plugin>
```

Unfortunately the collectd client will send the whole data set for each CPU and not only the warning, if the CPU reached the threshold. If I remove the cpu plugin, collectd will send nothing, neither the CPU details nor the warnings in case of triggering the threshold.

Is there an option to change the configuration that only the threshold related warnings will come but not the whole CPU details?

Redards

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aggregation plugin - https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Aggregation/Config.
Not sure if will work with Threshold plugin though.